# Trying to Create Two services in my application and send notifications from each, but the 2nd one replaces the 1st

Tags: android, android-service

I'm working on creating a 2nd service in my application, and since it does a completely different job from the 1st, I'd like them to send separate, un-related notifications.  However, the 2nd notification appears to be replacing the first in my status bar.

This is the notification code from my first service that seems to be working nicely:

```
private void showNotification()
{
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder (this)
            .setAutoCancel (true)
            .setSmallIcon (R.drawable.icon)
            .setWhen (System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle ("TCP Server Service Started");

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create (this);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent (new Intent (this, Launcher.class));                             //  This cannot be removed

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent (0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent (resultPendingIntent);

    notificationMngr.notify (0, mBuilder.build());
}
```

And I basically lifted that character for character and pasted it into my new service class.  Are either of those magic zeroes (in getPendingIntent(), and in notify()) parameters I should experiment to separate these??

Comment: yes, it's the zeroes. You can just increment a `static` variable to resolve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation.

> If the ID remains unchanged, the existing notification is updated.

There's also a pretty good example there as well. Check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html). Look for Updating Notifications.

Comment: So the ID is the 0 parameters on the notify() call?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes. You can click accept if the answer helped you as well.